# Installing ADB interfaces

Tags: android, adb, hardware

Good Day

I have this affordable Vodafone 890N manufactured by Yulong, I'm trying to use it to debug my android applications but for some reason i cannot find the appropriate abd driver online. if there's anyone who was able to get one for their devices, please share the link with me so I can download it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: used  `PdaNet` for ADB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the universal ADB driver should work. Dont forget to enable the debug on the device.

The github page of the universal ADB driver: https://github.com/koush/UniversalAdbDriver

Comment: Thank you Sandro, i got the universal ADB and everything is working perfectly. Thank you so much bro